# How to get the built-in contact form working in a CMS page in Magento?

Tags: php, xml, magento, contact-form, magento-1.7

I implemented the contact form into a CMS page [here](http://prodetailcarcare.evermight.com/2/contact/).

As you can see, the forms shows up fine.  However, when I fill the form out to test and click "send", there is no message indicating if the mail was sent correctly or failed.  But a new page loads, so I think it is doing something. When I check my email, no email comes.  I’ve checked spam folder too.

Current Setup:

In the CMS page, I have this code:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

In the form.phtml file, I have modified the form tag action attribute to:

```
<form action="/contacts/index/post/" id="contactForm" method="post">
```

Stuff I’ve tried already:

And I don’t think its the server because I tried the "forgot password” when logging into the Admin, and I received an email to reset the password.

In System Config, I’ve verified that "Enable Contact Us” is Yes.  "Disable EMail Communications” is No.  And makes no difference if "Set Return Path” is Yes or No.

It is set to send to an email address that is not hosted by the same server as the Magento site is on.  The email address is a Google Apps email.

Comment: If you are trying to send through Google Apps, you need to authenticate and connect through SSL/TLS. There is a thread over on the Magento Commerce forums, or you can use Ashley Shroder's extension over on Connect that allows this to be set up. Once that's functional, "Set Return Path" needs to be on with valid credentials or stuff falls into the spam traps. The entry on the CMS page and the form.phtml are correct and directly track what I'm using for this very application.

Comment: This was what I used (on ver 1.4.1.1) to get Google Apps attention http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/1073/#t19772

Comment: @FiascoLabs I should clarify, it's not a requirement to send emails _through_ Google Apps SMTP servers.  Using the default method to send emails is fine.  It just so happens that I'm trying to send emails _to_ my email address, which just so happens to be a Google Apps address.  I mentioned that because, I'm not trying to send to an address hosted on the same server as Magento (which I've read can cause issues).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.  For some reason, the path in the action attribute of  needed another parent folder.  So in my case, it should be

```
<form action="/2/contacts/index/post/" id="contactForm" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

just go to app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/template/contacts/form.phtml
and set form action to `<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>`

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
```